# Output format in **Kwargs

Tags: python-3.x, keyword-argument

I want to format my output like-
My choice of fruits are apple Avocado. But not sure it's not executing properly, maybe i'm missing something in formatting. Can you let me know where i'm doing it wrong?

```
 #Kwargs
def my_func(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
    if 'fruit' 'veggie' in kwargs:
        print('My choice of fruits are {} {}'.format(kwargs['fruit'],['veggie']))
    else:
        print('Sorry we can not find your fruit here!')

my_func(fruit='apple', veggie= 'Avocado')
```

Output of the above snippet coming as-
{'fruit': 'apple', 'veggie': 'Avocado'}
Sorry we can not find your fruit here!

Comment: if statement should be 'fruit' in kwargs and 'veggie' in kwargs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `'fruit' 'veggie' == 'fruitveggie'`
2. `['veggie']` is a `list` of `str`
3. find out about f-strings

So,

```
def my_func(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
    if 'fruit' in kwargs and 'veggie' in kwargs:
        print(f'My choice of fruits are {kwargs["fruit"]} {kwargs["veggie"]}')
    else:
        print('Sorry we can not find your fruit here!')

my_func(fruit='apple', veggie='Avocado')
```

Comment: Thanks. Even this line also works with your version of Code. print('My choice of fruits are {} {}'.format(kwargs['fruit'],kwargs['veggie']))